# No database selected error while using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this mysql_connect code which works perfectly fine -

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root'  );
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
```

but with the same details PDO gives error saying **No database selected**

```
<?php

$dbHost = 'mysql:host=localhost; dbname=db; charset=utf8';

$dbUser = "root";

    try {
    $conn = new PDO($dbHost, $dbUser);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

What is wrong with the PDO code ?

Comment: I think you missing a password

Comment: @Sadikhasan I have not set the password

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Newbie - the problem is that you are using `$conn` in your connection script and `$dbh->prepare` in query. It should be `$conn->prepare`

Answer (score 0):

DSN syntax is different from PHP syntax. You cannot use the PHP syntax considerations in DSN.
So, just follow examples you already have seen, don't try to decorate them.

```
$dbHost = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db;charset=utf8';
```

if you want host and db to be seen more distinctly - put them in variables

Also, you shouldn't catch here. So, the code should be like this

```
$dbHost = "localhost";
$dbBase = "db";
$dbChar = "utf8";
$dbUser = "root";
$dbPass = "";

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbBase;charset=$dbChar", $dbUser, $dbPass);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: and now again I get  `No database selected`

Comment: then check your variables

Comment: Thats wahts me wondering that with the same variable values `mysql_connect` works but not `pdo`

Comment: it works. I overengineered your code a bit, and made a mistake at first. but PDO works all right. All you need is drop these spaces. As for variables - just set **proper**  values for them

Comment: then check values again.

Comment: i have checked all the values, with the same user and host `my_connect` is wroking but not pdo. :(

Comment: then check again. there is a typo somewhere. write it over from scratch.

Comment: I tired even typing it from the scratch but don't know why it is not working

Comment: I tested this code (with my database name) and it worked for me.

Comment: Is it ok to have one script with this db connection code and than to include this script into the other php script ?

Comment: and is like I cant use `mysql_query` with `pdo` and I have to use something like -

$query = 'SELECT * FROM users where email = :email';

`$sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute(array(':email' => $autEmail));`

Comment: Yes to your first question. Yes, you should make it this way with pdo. You need one more line though: $user = $sth->fetch(). BTW, you can check my PDO wrapper, it makes PDO as easy as old mysql: https://github.com/colshrapnel/thebestpdowrapper

Comment: ohh thn thats the reason why it was not working ..!!
Thankx for your help and patience :)

Comment: one last thing .. wht is wrong with this query - 


`$testType = 'TCL';
 
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT testcases2.testcaseID, testcases2.testName, testcases2.script, testcases2.testType, results3.status, results3.testRunID, results3.platform
FROM testcases2
INNER JOIN results3 ON testcases2.testcaseID = results3.testcaseID 
WHERE testcases2.testType = :testType');

$sth->execute(array(':testType' => $testType));

while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo $row['title'];
}`

Comment: I get these two errors - `Undefined variable: dbh` and `Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object `

Comment: these errors are quite obvious. you have to understand the code you are using, not just copy-paste it mindlessly